# How to compute Bernoulli's solution to St. Petersburg paradox

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm triyng to understand the St.Petersburg paradox and the solution provided by Bernoulli: we are solving it assuming the utility is $ln(x)$. To solve it I must solve the following infinite sum:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{ln(2^k)}{2^k}$
and the solution should be $ln(4)$.

The problem is that I'm not able to find such solution, it doesn't seem to be a geometric series and even if i can solve the sum $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=2 $ i have no idea how to address the logarithm. I've tried to express it as a series of $ ln(2) $ but I'm not sure how to do it.

I think that to solve it I have to express it as $ \frac{ln2}{2}+\frac{2ln2}{4}+\frac{3ln2}{8}+...\frac{ln(2^k)}{2^k}$, then collect $ln(2)$ but i can't solve the final steps: how do I move forward from
${ln(2)}[\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+...\frac{k}{2^k}]$

Is it the right path or I've messed up something, are there easier solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you yourself notice, we can write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(2^k)}{2^k}=\log(2)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}.
$$
It is straightforward to show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}=\frac{2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^n}=2-\frac{n}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}
$$
for all positive integers $n$ by induction. We thus get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(2^k)}{2^k}=\log(2)\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(2-\frac{n}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\bigg)=2\log(2)=\log(4)
$$
as was to be shown.